# SSL Certificate validation with AFNetworking

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I understand the use and necessity of SSL Certificates. I am looking for a detailed explanation of the relationship between http protocol and SSL Certificate and also between https and SSL Certificate.

In AFNetworking defining _AFNETWORKING_ALLOW_INVALID_SSL_CERTIFICATES_ allows invalid certificates.
Assuming this flag is not set, the library should deny invalid certificates by default. But what if the server has no certificate installed at its end? I see that I can access a server with no certificate using http protocol.

And does the default certificate validation occur for https protocol only?

I want to access only those servers with a certificate and which are valid over http and https? Is this feature required and if so is it possible?

Comment: If it does, I'd file a bug report about it.  You can't handshake with a server that doesn't even have hands to shake with.

Comment: Yea, what you said makes at most sense. But I am experiencing something different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you don't understand what HTTP and HTTPS are about:

- http is the session protocol to communicate with servers without encryption. Everything is sent in the clear and there is also no way to verify the authenticity of the server (i.e. that the server responding is indeed having the correct hostname). A server doesn't need an SSL certificate in this case.
- https is used when you want to ensure that communication with the server is encrypted. For this, the server needs an SSL certificate and before anything is sent over the HTTP session, a handshake will take place allowing the client to fetch the SSL certificate of the server in order to encrypt the data that is sent. So an SSL certificate is only used for HTTPS connections.

It is also possible to verify the authenticity of the server, depending on the SSL certificate used. All browsers (and by default on iOS, unless you explicitely change this in your app) will only accept SSL certificates that have been issued by known certification authorities. This way you can be sure that the server is indeed located at the hostname you requested. Depending on the SSL certificate the owner of the server might also be verified (i.e. that the server indeed belongs to the company it claims to belong to).